# Python script is returning function not defined error

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I am writing a python class and trying to call a function from another function in the class but I am running into an error.`NameError: name 'bobfunction' is not defined`.  My call to the class works, even the call to method/function job works.  When `job` tries to call `bobfunction` I get the error message.  removing the call to `bobfunction` works.  So how do I call the bobfunction from the job function?

```
class stuff():
    def __init__(self):
        #setup stuff

     def bobfunction(self,junk):
         print("should work")
         return ''

      def job(self,data):
          bobfunction('test data')
          return 'other junk'
```

Comment: Your indentation seems to be offset. The `def` in job function should align with `def` in bobfunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it with `self.bobfunction("test data")`

Python uses the keyword `self` to refer to class methods and variables of the same class. It is similar to `this` keyword in other languages. (Not the same though) . If you end up defining a variable in your `__init__` function , you can also use it with `self.variable_name` in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run it with stuff.bobfunction(self,"test data")
Because bobfunction was situated in class stuff, you need to write class' name before function's name.
Self in parentheses must send the name of self.